# get text inside elements from class name using scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

How can I get the first text, I mean "Quotes to Scrape", from the following element using class name by scrapy python?

```
<div class="col-md-8">
                <h1>
                    <a href="/" style="text-decoration: none">Quotes to Scrape</a>
                </h1>
            </div>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reasonable list of selectors both for css and xpath.[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please don't hide critical information in images. Images are great for supplementing answers, but they can be hard to read, can't be consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers, can't be searched or copied, and can't be indexed or searched. Text is _vastly_ better.

Answer (score 0):

The element has no class, but you can get the text like this:

```
response.css('h1 a::text').get()
```